# How to configure muliple bucket in spring-boot couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I am new to couchbase and using couchbase 5.1. A single spring boot application the database config only takes a single bucket name.

Is it possible to connect to more than one couchbase bucket in spring-boot? If yes, then how i can implement it ?

Here is my code

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example" })
public class MyCouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

 @Override
 protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
     CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().connectTimeout(150000).build();
     return env;
 }

 @Override
 protected List < String > getBootstrapHosts() {
     return Arrays.asList("localhost");
 }

 @Override
 protected String getBucketName() {
     return "student";
 }

 @Override
 protected String getBucketPassword() {
     return "123456";
 }

 @Override
 public String typeKey() {
     return MappingCouchbaseConverter.TYPEKEY_SYNCGATEWAY_COMPATIBLE;
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many buckets as possible using `com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster#openBucket` so to add another bucket, make your class look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = {
 "com.example"
})
public class MyCouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {


 /* ... ALL YOUR CODE FROM EARLIER ... */


 @Bean
 public Bucket anotherBucket() throws Exception {
  return couchbaseCluster().openBucket("bucket2", "password");
 }

 // if using repositories you need to create another template and
 // override the entity<->template mapping
 @Bean
 public CouchbaseTemplate anotherTemplate() throws Exception {
  CouchbaseTemplate template = new CouchbaseTemplate(
   couchbaseClusterInfo(), anotherBucket(),
   mappingCouchbaseConverter(), translationService());
  template.setDefaultConsistency(getDefaultConsistency());
  return template;
 }

 @Override
 public void configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(
  RepositoryOperationsMapping baseMapping) {
  try {
   baseMapping.mapEntity(AnotherEntity.class, anotherTemplate());
  } catch (Exception e) {
   //custom Exception handling
  }
 }

}
```